# Lexer using C++ and Regex

Tags: c++, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to create a very basic compiler, and I'm working on the lexer. 
I decided to store keywords and operators in an unordered_set, and use regex to match identifiers and literals (no comments yet).

**Tokens.h**

```
#ifndef TOKENS_H
#define TOKENS_H

#include<unordered_set>
#include<string>
namespace AVSL
{
    enum class TokenType
    {
        Identifier,
        Keyword,
        String,
        Literal,
        Comment,
        Operator,
        Delim
    };

    static const std::unordered_set<std::string> keywords = { "var", "for", "while", "print", "constant"};
    static const std::unordered_set<std::string> operators = { "+", "-", "*", "/", "=", "==", "+=", "-=", "*=", "/=" };
    static const std::unordered_set<char> delims = { '(', ')', ';' };
    static const std::unordered_set<char> whitespace = { '\n', '\r', '\t', ' ' };


    struct Token
    {
        std::string tokenValue;
        TokenType tokenType;

        Token() = delete;

        Token(const std::string& tokenValue_, TokenType tokenType_): tokenValue(tokenValue_), tokenType(tokenType_){ /* empty */ }

        Token(const Token& token): tokenValue(token.tokenValue), tokenType(token.tokenType) { /* empty */ }


    };
}

#endif
```

**Lexer.h**

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include "Tokens.h"

using LineNo = unsigned int;
namespace AVSL
{
    std::vector<Token> Tokenize(std::string filename);
    Token getToken(std::string buffer, LineNo line);
}


#endif
```

**Lexer.cpp**

```
#include "Lexer.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
namespace AVSL
{
    Token getToken(std::string buffer, LineNo line)
    {
        if (operators.find(buffer) != operators.end())
        {
            return Token(buffer, TokenType::Operator);
        }
        else if (keywords.find(buffer) != keywords.end())
        {
            return Token(buffer, TokenType::Keyword);
        }

        std::regex iden("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
        std::regex str("\".*\"");
        std::regex lit("^[0-9]+$");
        //std::regex;

        if (std::regex_match(buffer, iden))
        {
            return Token(buffer, TokenType::Identifier);
        }
        if (std::regex_match(buffer, str))
        {
            return Token(buffer, TokenType::String);
        }
        if (std::regex_match(buffer, lit))
        {
            return Token(buffer, TokenType::Literal);
        }


        /* No support for comments yet*/

        /* Will only reach here if all else fails, invalid string */

        std::cout << "Invalid expression at line number " << line << " : " << buffer;
        std::cin.get();
        exit(0);

    }


    std::vector<Token> Tokenize(std::string filename)
    {
        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

        if (file.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to open file!\n";
            std::cin.get();
            exit(0);
        }

        LineNo line = 1;
        std::string buffer = "";

        char ch;
        std::vector<Token> tokens;

        while (file >> std::noskipws >> ch)
        {
            if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                line += 1;

            if (delims.find(ch) != delims.end())
            {
                if (buffer != "")
                {
                    tokens.push_back(getToken(buffer, line));
                    buffer = "";
                }
                tokens.push_back(Token(std::string(1, ch), TokenType::Delim));
                continue;
            }

            else if (whitespace.find(ch) != whitespace.end())
            {
                if (buffer != "")
                {
                    tokens.push_back(getToken(buffer, line));
                    buffer = "";
                }
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                buffer += ch;
            }

        }

        //std::cout << line << "\n";

        return tokens;

    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Tokens.h"
#include "Lexer.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<fstream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<AVSL::TokenType, std::string> tokenMap = { {AVSL::TokenType::Keyword, "Keyword"}, {AVSL::TokenType::Identifier, "Identifier"}, {AVSL::TokenType::Operator, "Operator"}, {AVSL::TokenType::Literal, "Literal"}, {AVSL::TokenType::Delim, "Delim" } };

    auto vec =  AVSL::Tokenize("dummy.txt");

    for (auto x : vec)
    {
        std::cout << x.tokenValue << "->" << tokenMap.find(x.tokenType)->second << "\n";
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The lexer works fine so far. On a dummy file:
`var i = 42;`
It prints out:

```
var->Keyword
i->Identifier
=->Operator
42->Literal
;->Delim
```

Also, on invalid inputs, it will print out the line number and invalid string:

```
var i = 42;



i += 2a;
```

`Invalid expression at line number 5 : 2a`

Any advice/comments would be appreciated. I'm mostly concerned of error handling. Right now, all it does is print to stdout and exit the program.

Comment: I'm afraid the regex approach will get back at you once you start using escape sequences, literal escapes, quoting, etc. => str = "my \"quoted\" string" or \u0022my string started with an escape sequence"

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Great first question!  Not only is the code clear, and the title good, but you've also done a good job of showing the context with an example.  I look forward to seeing more good questions from you!

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1

Comment: I would look into how to use Lex/Bison most of this can be done automatically with the correct tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Use all required `#include`s

The `Lexer.h` file uses `std::string` and `std::vector` as part of its interface, but does not include `<vector>` at all, and only indirectly includes `<string>` because that's part of `Tokens.h`.  I'd recommend explicitly putting both `<vector>` *and* `<string>` in `Lexer.h` so that if, for example, one wanted to alter the interface for `Token` to not use `std::string`, this file would still remain the same.

### Eliminate unused variables

In this program's `main()`, `argc`, `argv` are unused and should be eliminated from the program.  Or perhaps use the next suggestion instead.

### Allow the user to specify input file

The file names are currently hardcoded which certainly greatly restricts the usefulness of the program.  Consider using `argc` and `argv` to allow the user to specify file names on the command line.

### Consider allowing a `std::istream` parameter for input

As it stands, the `Tokenize()` function is only capable of reading its input from a file with the passed name, but not, say, `std::cin` or any other stream.  Instead of handling file I/O there, change it to take a `std::istream &`.  This makes the function much more flexible and also somewhat smaller and simpler.

### Keep associated things closer together

Right now there is an `AVSL::TokenTyp::Keyword` and an `unordered_map` that contains the string "Keyword" and a list of `keywords` and then part of the parser also looks for those.  They are literally spread out over all files.  Keeping associated things together is exactly a job for an object.  First, I'd rename `TokenType` to `Type` and put it inside `struct Token` so now we have `Token::Type` everywhere that `TokenType` is currently used.  Next, we could create a more generic `Classifier` class:

```
class Classifier {
public:
    Classifier(Token::Type ttype, std::string name, std::unordered_set<std::string> tokens) :
        my_type{ttype},
        my_name{name},
        my_tokens{tokens}
    {}
    bool among(const std::string& word) const { return my_tokens.find(word) != my_tokens.end(); }
    Token::Type type() const { return my_type; }
private:
    Token::Type my_type;
    std::string my_name;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> my_tokens;
};

static const std::vector<Classifier> classifiers {
    { Token::Type::Keyword, "Keyword", { "var", "for", "while", "print", "constant"} },
    { Token::Type::Operator, "Operator", { "+", "-", "*", "/", "=", "==", "+=", "-=", "*=", "/=" } },
};
```

Now the first part of `getToken` could look like this:

```
for (const auto &thing : classifiers) {
    if (thing.among(buffer)) {
        return Token(buffer, thing.type());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, one could include a function in the `Token` class that would emit the type name for printing.  If you have C++17, I'd suggest returning a `std::string_view` for that purpose.

### Wrap the regex operations into classes

It's not too difficult to imagine how, like the basic static `Classifier` object above, one could use a slightly more sophisticated version to employ a `std::regex`.  If you have both kinds of classifiers derive from the same base object, then even more goodness can happen because now your code is *data-driven* which makes things easier to maintain and to understand.

### Use a standard tool instead

There are a lot of inefficiencies with the current code.  For one thing, the same buffer is scanned many times in trying to find a match.  This is very inefficient and will make a big difference with larger files or more complex lexers.  I'd recommend instead using [`flex++`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) instead to create a lexer which is both very easy to maintain and read and also very efficient and fast.

Comment: Thanks! I've thought a lot about utilizing Flex or some other parser generator, but this project is purely for my own academic interests and for such a lightweight "language", it seems overkill. Maybe if I do decide to implement more features, I might use something like that. 
Also, I really liked the idea of using `Classifier` class, and I might do something like that. :)

Comment: In my experience, the time invested in learning how to use `flex` and `bison` **far** outweighed the time spent creating my own lexers and parsers in terms of value received for time spent.  The latest releases of both have much improved C++ interfaces and facilities, so if you'd looked at them before but didn't spend time on them because they seemed very C-centric, it may well be worth another look.